# Which version of Spring Data MongoDB is compatible with Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, compatibility, spring-data-mongodb

I am currently using mongo-java-driver 3.0.1. I am trying to use Spring Data Mongodb with Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE. Is there any way i can find out which version of Spring Data MongoDB should i use, in order to be compatible with Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE? Some kind of compatibility matrix.

Comment: I am kind of stuck with the similar situation.If you had solution with this please let me know.I am using java driver 3.0 in the current code base.Looking to implement spring data in parallel to support the same driv er

Answer (score 1):

Try define your spring data mongodb dependency at the last of the dependency tree in your pom

Answer (score 0):

You can [check the compiled dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/1.5.6.RELEASE) of Spring Data Mongodb.
Here are the most compatible options for Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE:

```
spring-data-mongodb 1.5.6.RELEASE depends on spring-core 3.2.22.RELEASE
spring-data-mongodb 1.4.3.RELEASE depends on spring-core 3.2.8.RELEASE
```