# What's the last version of Spring Data MongoDB compatible with Spring 3.2?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, wiredtiger

I need to use WiredTiger Engine in my application which is available in the latest mongodb version 3.2.2 and my Maven repository which is using the version Spring Data MongoDB version 1.8.4, Java driver version 2.13.3 and I've installed MongoDB version 2.6.11.

Which version of spring-data-mongodb should i use, in order to be compatible with Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE?

This is the duplicate of the following unanswered question :

[Which version of Spring Data MongoDB is compatible with Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338095/which-version-of-spring-data-mongodb-with-spring-3-2-2-release)

But I don't have enough privilege  to re-ask or comment on the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last Spring Data release train compatible with Spring 3.2 is [Dijkstra](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Dijkstra) and has seen its last service release January 27th, 2015. The Spring Data MongoDB version contained in it is 1.5.5.RELEASE.

Note that this version is not compatible with any MongoDB 3.x version. MongoDB 3.x support was introduced in the [Fowler release train](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Fowler) and is refined in even more current releases only. So I am strongly suggesting to upgrade to one of those versions if you want to work with a MongoDB of that generation.

Comment: Thanks Oliver for the response.On the given reference page, it is mentioned that the participating module version for spring data mongo db is 1.7. So I can go with version 1.7

Comment: No. The Dijkstra page lists Spring Data MongoDB 1.5, the SR5 then turning it into 1.5.5, depending on Spring 3.2.9. The *Fowler* page refers to Spring Data MongoDB 1.7 but requires Spring 4.0.9 at least.